# ListObject Error upon applying an Unlist Method

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery, listobject, excel-tables

Basically, I have an Excel Formatted Table called "TestTable" in my activesheet. That's the only table in that sheet. I'm trying to convert it to a normal range. From looking up online, this should be simple, all I have to do is `Unlist` that table object.
However, my VBA code is throwing an error. Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub ConverToNormalRange()
Dim objListObj As ListObject
Set objListObj = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
objListObj.Unlist
End Sub
```

When I run the above macro, I get the following error:

[image: Error upon calling Unlist method on ListObject]

Comment: when you click debug, which line is highlighted?

Comment: @ScottCraner objListObj.Unlist

Comment: maybe objListObj is nothing.  Try this: Put `If objListObj is nothing then debug.print "nothing"` before the unlist line and see if it returns `nothing` in the immediate window.

Comment: There is something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried converting the table manually and it wasn't doing anything either. So then I figured it wasn't a VBA problem. It turns out that I had connections open in Power Query, and it was preventing the table from converting back to normal range.

[image: Open power query connections don't allow you to convert table to normal range]

Answer (score 0):

### Convert First Table to a Range

```vb
Sub ConvertToRange()
    Const ProcName As String = "ConvertToRange"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    With ActiveSheet ' improve!
        If .ListObjects.Count > 0 Then
            Dim tblName As String
            With .ListObjects(1)
                tblName = .Name
                .Unlist
            End With
            MsgBox "Table '" & tblName & "' converted to a range.", _
                vbInformation
        Else
            MsgBox "No table found in worksheet '" & .Name & "'.", _
                vbExclamation
        End If
    End With

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

Comment: 'ConvertToRange' Run-time error '1004':
    Application-defined or object-defined error